# How to pass dataframe to spark udf?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, user-defined-functions

I want to define a udf. In the function body, it will search data from external dataframe. How can I do that? I tried to pass the dataframe to udf. But it cannot work.

Sample code:

```
val countryDF = spark.read
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .option("header", "true")
  .csv("Country.csv")

val geo = (originString: String, dataFrame: DataFrame) => {
  // Search data from countryDF
  val row = dataFrame.where(col("CountryName") === originString)
  if (row != Nil){
    // set data to row index 2
    row.getAs[String](2)
  }
  else{
    "0"
  }
}
val udfGeo = udf(geo)

val cLatitudeAndLongitude = udfGeo(countryTestDF.col("CountryName"), lit(countryDF))

countryTestDF = countryTestDF.withColumn("Latitude", cLatitudeAndLongitude)
```

Comment: `lit` can be used for strings. we can't parse dataframe to UDF.

Comment: if I understand correctly, you may use below code [change the when condition ]
`countryDF.withColumn("cLatitudeAndLongitudeFlag", when(col("CountryName") === "originString" , "1").otherwise("0")).select("cLatitudeAndLongitudeFlag").distinct.show()`

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the unclear code. I changed the code a little. Actually,  the function is to set row(2) instead of "1" if found row in dataframe countryDF. Then how can I implement it? Do you mean dataframe cannot be passed to UDF?

Comment: countryTestDF is final dataframe. The task is to search each cell of column "CountryName" from another dataframe countryDF. If found a record. Get the data of corresponding row (column index is 2).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a UDF, you have to work on columns, not on dataframe object
You have to create a new column that take the output of the UDF.

```
def geo(originString : String, CountryName: String) : Int = {

    if (CountryName == originString){
      return 1}
    else{
      return 0}
  }

val geoUDF = udf(geo _)

val newData = countryDF.withColum("isOrignOrNot", geoUDF(col("originString"),col("CountryName"))
```